# How to create Add / Delete Dropdown Box rows populated by mySQL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, addition

Yes, I have been trying to create this form for about 3 days now. I had everything working, but when validation was needed to see if inputs were filled out, everything got out of control.

The form needs to have a dropdown box that is populated by mySQL values. There will be a textbox beside that for input as well. The textbox needs to be validated by javascript to check if an input is in the textbox. Then, a button for deleting the row.

The add button should be above all of this and just add another row of the same inputs.

I had this working with innerHTML statements and passing everything into a PHP array using a counter, but it has gotten just too complicated with the delete button and validation.

I'm using jQuery in other parts of the web application, so that is an option.

Any direction or sample code would be a great help.

Thank you

**Was able to get it working with this code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
if(typeof intId==='undefined')
{
     $(".add").attr("disabled", "true");
}
$("#addButton").click(function() {
    var intId = $("#prodpart div").length + 1;
    var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" id=\"partfield" + intId +     "\"/>");
    var partlabel = $("<label>Part #" + intId + ":</label>&nbsp;");
    var part = $("<select name=\"part[" + intId + "]\"><?php echo $option2; ?></select>");
    var partqtylabel = $("<label>Part QTY #" + intId + ":&nbsp;</label>&nbsp;");
    var partqty = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"required\" onblur=\"enable()\"     value=\"\" size=\"5\" id=\"partqty" + intId + "\" name=\"partqty[" + intId + "]\" class=\"fieldname\" />");
    var parttimelabel = $("<label> Run Time #" + intId + ":</label>&nbsp;");
    var parttime = $("<input type=\"text\" size=\"5\" value=\"NOT REQUIRED\" name=\"runparttime[" + intId + "]\" />");
    var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"Del\" />");
    removeButton.click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    fieldWrapper.append(partlabel);
    fieldWrapper.append(part);
    fieldWrapper.append(partqtylabel);
    fieldWrapper.append(partqty);
    fieldWrapper.append(parttimelabel);
    fieldWrapper.append(parttime);
    fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
    $("#prodpart").append(fieldWrapper);
    });
});
function disable(){
$(".add").attr("disabled", "true");
$(".required").blur(function(){
    if ($(this).val() != initVal && $(this).val() != "") {
    $(".add").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
    $(".add").attr("disabled", "true");        
    }
}); 
};
function enable(){
    $(".add").removeAttr("disabled");
};
```

This is javascript above for writing the rows, deleting, and for validation.

```
<input type="button" value="Add Prod Part" class="add" onclick="disable()" id="addButton" />
```

One of my buttons. Before you enter text in the required boxes, the buttons are disabled. Once text has been entered, the buttons enable and you can add another row. This is still a little buggy but works just fine for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I built something similar recently, and what I had was the following:

1. At the start all the rows, cells and field are generated and populated from the mySQL DB.
2. All the input types are in a table row.
3. On the left hand side are ordering numbers. This allows people to reorder their data.
4. I then had an interactive "reorder" function which allows the rows to shift automatically.
5. The "delete" function was on the right of each row; deleting a row would shift it to the bottom, then remove the bottom row.
6. The "add" function would add a table row with `table.insertRow(table.rows.length);` and insert the relevant data.

To top it all off, I also had a "row count" variable which was incremented/decremented by the add/delete buttons respectively.

The data verification then becomes a `for` loop on all of the table rows (using the "row count"). Good luck with making this - it wasn't easy for me, and I would post the source code, but I don't think it is quite what you are looking for (no validation and lots of table data colums are already preset).

Comment: You are right, it is not easy. I have made some progress, but I am about to start the validation javascript and see if I can figure it out. Thank you for your input though. I might put mine into a table soon